# CODEIGNITER: Return a PDF file from controller using readfile()

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

In one of my CODEIGNITER projects I have following code that is working nicely:

```
  $this->output
       ->set_content_type('application/pdf')
       ->set_output(file_get_contents($file));
```

To make code memory friendly I want to use the php function **readfile()** in place of **file_get_contents()** but its not working properly.

I have noted that readfile() works if I return an **image** but does not work with **PDF**.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: what does `file_get_contents($file)` return? A boolean? string?

Comment: can you plz let me know if $file is local folder path of file or its url of file? because readfile() function only accept local folder path of file but file_get_contents() can accepts both.

Comment: $file is a local file, NOT a url.  I have already mentioned above that readfile() is working fine if I try to return an image. But if I try to return PDF, it will just return unformatted string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation on [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) clearly states that it just outputs the file to the browser. It just echoes the file to stdout and returns the number of bytes read from the file. If you want to use the function, you'll have to NOT use the CodeIgniter output functions. You'll need to use the more raw, basic PHP header functions instead. Something like this:

```
$filepath = "/path/to/file.pdf";
// EDIT: I added some permission/file checking.
if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
    throw new Exception("File $filepath does not exist");
}
if (!is_readable($filepath)) {
    throw new Exception("File $filepath is not readable");
}
http_response_code(200);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"'); // feel free to change the suggested filename
readfile($filepath);

exit; // this is important so that CodeIgniter doesn't parse any more output to ruin your file download
```

**NOTE:** If the permissions on $filepath are not readable to the user executing this code (your user, apache, www-data, httpd, etc.) then you might get a *file is not readable* error. You can also get a *file does not exist* error if the file itself is readable but the directory in which it exists is not. **Check the permissions on the file itself and the directory in which that file resides.**

Comment: I tried this but got a message "Failed to load PDF document". Path is correct & file exists because if I use file_get_contents() then its showing. What else need to be done?

Comment: I added some error checking to my code to first check if the file exists or is readable. I also added some advice to my post about file permissions. I tested this code on a file that **www-data** didn't have permission for and it returned 'file does not exist.' I tested it on a file with correct permissions and it worked just fine.

Comment: Here is the complete method code. Also read my next comment below. `public function get_file($file)
{

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    throw new Exception("File $file does not exist");
}
if (!is_readable($file)) {
    throw new Exception("File $file is not readable");
}
http_response_code(200);
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"'); 
readfile($file);

exit;  

}`

Comment: NO, still its not working. No exception was thrown. There is no issue of file existence or permissions because if i place following code in above method, it displays PDF successfully.`/*
// WORKING CODE for PDF
      $this->output
           ->set_content_type('application/pdf')
           ->set_output(file_get_contents($file));            
*/
            
 `

Comment: I am shocked. Its working on only EDGE(Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0) but not working on CHROME (Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)) & FIREFOX (49.0) !

Comment: @MyO From where I sit, I cannot corroborate that you are passing all of your information correctly. I have in fact tested the code I posted and it works just fine for me. I suggest you inspect the contents of the var $file.

Comment: @MyO I'm using Firefox 50.1.0 on Ubuntu and it works fine on my machine. Question: are you passing $file in as a parameter via the URL? If so, this could present a serious security problem. -- it might also be the reason why the code isn't working. Different browsers might url-encode things differently. I'd strongly suggest that you do NOT let folks specify the file to be downloaded directly in the url without some serious scrutiny or they might end up requesting your sensitive data, like application/config/database.php or email credentials or something.

Comment: @MyO This might have something to do with plugins installed or something? Try commenting out the content-disposition line. Alternatively, your app might be sending data to the browser before/after this code actually runs, which would break things. Make sure you check for errors -- you might have to look in the error log if you have display_errors off or if CI is in production mode.

Comment: Actually I am testing the suitable way of providing secured PDF files to the  logged in users. Files are stored above the root. So they are not directly accessible through url. User clicks the file link in the view. User credentials are checked in the controller & then get_file() method executes to provide the file. I also use it to render secured images. How  else I can perform this task?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132941/discussion-between-s-imp-and-myo).

Answer (score -1):

**Try below code if you are sure about mimetype of file**

```
$contents = read_file($file);
    $this->output
            ->set_status_header(200)
            ->set_content_type('application/pdf')
            ->set_output($contents)
            ->_display();
    exit;
```

**If you are not sure about the mimetype of file then**

```
$this->load->helper('file');

$file = '/path/to/pdf/file';
$contents = read_file($file);

 $this->output
        ->set_status_header(200)
        ->set_content_type(get_mime_by_extension($file_path))
        ->set_output($contents)
        ->_display();
```

Reference:- https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: This code wrongly assumes that readfile returns the contents of the file. This is not the case at all.